# Add plural forms to the string “Browse other questions tagged...”

Tags: feature-request, tags, localization, plurals

On the bottom of the almost each question’s page you can see the following:

> [image: other questions]

In case of localized sites (I look from the side of the Stack Overflow in Russian) knowing the number (one/few/many) of tags used in resulting string could help to improve the quality of the translation.

Is it possible to add plural forms to the following two sentences at least?

> [Browse other questions tagged $QuestionTagLinks$.](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265331?key=7297487e4d2df1baa8c6419ccd6ce9a5)
>
> [Browse other questions tagged $QuestionTagLinks$ or [ask your own question]($ask$).](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265332?key=8483753d2e45a256a40f46a08c7d4cf9)

E.g. Based on the number of tags we could translate the first sentence as the following:

- 1: "Посмотрите другие вопросы с **меткой** $QuestionTagLinks$."
- 2-N: "Посмотрите другие вопросы с **метками** $QuestionTagLinks$."

Comment: Just FYI: to get this on SE's radar, a [tag:status-review] tag needs be added to the question. Posting a bounty brings more attention from regular users, which is helpful when the issue needs more support or input from users, but doesn't bring it to attention of Stack Overflow staff. Adding the [tag:status-review] tag generates a ticket in SE's task system, which they will then triage into an actual feature request/bug sent to developers. To have a status-review tag added to the question, the normal process is to raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag to request the tag be added.

Comment: @Makyen are moderators eligible to add "status-review" only based on their own vision?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking in your comment. You might want to look at "[What posts should be escalated to staff using \[status-review\], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/271271)" I've also posted a longer response covering a couple of different meanings in the Teachers' Lounge, because it's easier to chat there than here in comments.