# Add plural forms to the string about an answer converted to a comment

Tags: feature-request, migration, localization, russian-stackoverflow, plurals

String: `5af795a4c61ad499ad30bd3442f2d38f`.

Original variant:

> **This answer is hidden**. This answer was deleted and converted to a comment $deletionDatePreSpan$$deletionDate$$deletionDatePostSpan$ by $deletingUsers$.

The English text includes **by**, and it doesn't matter if it was converted by one, two or more members.

But in Russian it does matter. Could you add plural forms (one, few, many) for this string?

Comment: I found yet another case: `af68baf6358a640f3629917bf393a5ae` - "Closed $closedAgo$ by $closeUsersComma$."

Comment: Related FR for tags: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305961/339911