# Plural forms are needed for close notice

Tags: bug, closed-questions, localization, plurals

There's only [single form](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13645) for question close notice:

> Closed $closedAgo$ by $closeUsersComma$.

For the purpose of localization we need different plural forms for that type of sentence since `$closeUsersComma$` may contain one (mod or dupe-hammer vote) or more user names.

Related question about tags: [Add plural forms to the string “Browse other questions tagged...”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305961/339911)